Calculating churn rate in SQL: how can I display both churned and not churned customer in % in a single query?
I'm using the IBM Telco dataset and here's a sample of the table:



CustomerID
churn_value




101
1


102
0



churn_value = 1 represents customers who churned this quarter and 0 for those who haven't. I wanted to calculate the churn rate and to display how many customers churned in % and how many didn't.
The formula for churn rate: **(Lost Customers ÷ Total Customers at the Start of Time Period) x 100.
**
The lost customers are those whose churn_value = 1, so:
select count (*) as churned_customers
from Telco_customer_churn where churn_value=1;

The total customers all of them without using any filter:
select count(*) as total_customers
from Telco_customer_churn;

I know I can just take the values from both queries and put them into the formula like:
1869/7043 * 100 = 26.5% churned
7043-1869 = 5174/7043 * 100 = 73.4% not churned
I can't figure out how to make it into one query. I want it to be displayed as:



churned
not_churned




26.5
73.4



How do I make it to percentage? I'm also confused because because the where clause applies on all rows for the query and so how can I calculate it all in the same query?
Maybe a subquery is needed? I'd appreciate any help.

You're looking for conditional aggregation e.g. sum(case when...)

As mentioned by @Dale K, this can be done using the conditional aggregation :
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_value = 1 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS churned,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN churn_value = 0 THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS not_churned
FROM mytable

